# Ruby cannot route to site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to list all doctors in my project using `<%= link_to 'Registration to visit', doctors_index51_path %>` but I get error: `Couldn't find Doctor with id=index51`
I have added get "doctors/index51" to routes and I have something like this in doctors_controller:

```
  def index51
    @doctors = Doctor.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index51.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @doctors }
    end
  end
```

Routes.rb:

```
ZOZ::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :refferals


  resources :clinics


  resources :doctors

  get "welcome/index2"

  get "welcome/index"

  get "patients/select51"

  get "patients/show51"

  get "refferals/new"


  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  resources :patients

  resources :doctors do
    collection do
      get 'index51'
    end
  end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  root :to => 'welcome#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

Help me please, I am new in Ruby and I'm fighting with my project to school :)

In rake routes output I have:
index51_doctors GET /doctors/index51 (.:format) doctors#index51

Error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in DoctorsController#show

Couldn't find Doctor with id=index51
Rails.root: D:/Studia/Bazy Danych/Projekt/Implementacja/ZOZ

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/doctors_controller.rb:25:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"index51"}
```

Comment: What's the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Looks like you have setup a member route rather than a collection route.  What have you got in routes.rb?

Comment: Rake routes shows me that I have doctors_index51_path, I don't know what is wrong because I have the same with patients_select51_path and there is no problem :)

Comment: @user3742883 can you post your rake routes in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably this is what you need.

```
 resources :doctors do
    collection do
      get 'index51'
    end
  end
```

edit: (after routes.rb was posted)
comment 4th statement

`#resources :doctors`

Its defined twice, isn't it?

Comment: should I change link_to because now I get error undefined local variable or method `doctors_index51_path' ?:)

Comment: Ok, I have clear this error because now is index51_doctors_path but now I have returned to previous error Couldn't find Doctor with id=index51

Comment: how does the link look like? run `rake routes`

Comment: <%= link_to 'Register visit', index51_doctors_path %>

Comment: replaced with previous routes? refresh the page once

Comment: I still refreshed and nothing happened, there must be something wrong in other place because in routes.rb I have ypur code

Comment: restart your server once.

Comment: did that and nothing also happened

Comment: `GET  /doctors/index51(.:format)  doctors#index51` is this what you see?

Comment: yes, and before that I have index51_doctors.
maybe it will be helpfull that I have also in error app/controllers/doctors_controller.rb:25:in `show' and {"id"=>"index51"}

Comment: update the Question with routes.rb file and rake routes output and the error as well

Comment: Thanks so much :) You are my Ruby Man :D

Comment: U must be kidding :D that's ok, there is lot to learn, keep basics tight, you will do well :)

Comment: I keep practise C#, Ruby is only needed for pass my subject in school :D I am not kiddin, really appreciate your help, your ruined time for reading this fully of mistakes code and thanks you again ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to achieve what your want!

`get "doctors/index51", to: "doctors#index51"`

and what you have done is usually works in static pages!

Hope to help!

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at your routes file and noticed you are using routes like *get "patients/select51"
and get "patients/show51"*

What these routes do? select patient with id 51 and show patient with id 51? `You are not making rails RESTful routes`. You should look into [rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to get a better idea of what exactly is going on

`Error: Couldn't find Doctor with id=index51` states that rails is looking at index51 as an id.

**Fix:**

You have `resources :doctors` inside your routes.rb file which creates seven different routes in your application, all mapping to the doctors controller like:

```
GET /doctors    doctors#index   display a list of all doctors
GET /doctors/new    doctors#new return an HTML form for creating a new doctor
POST  /doctors  doctors#create  create a new doctor
GET /doctors/:id    doctors#show    display a specific doctor
GET /doctors/:id/edit   doctors#edit    return an HTML form for editing a doctor
PATCH/PUT   /doctors/:id    doctors#update  update a specific doctor
DELETE  /photos/:id doctors#destroy delete a specific doctor
```

and below that you have:

```
resources :doctors do
 collection do
  get 'index51'
 end
end
```

which is creating a `get /doctors/index51 doctors#index51` and conflicting so you need to remove the earlier one. Although i'll still suggest sticking with the defaults but that will require you to make an action index rather than index51

Comment: @user3742883 I know it wasn't problem and i was editing my answer for solution but still its not rails way and your routes are not RESTful that's all i'm saying :)

Comment: I know and you have right of course because I have to use Ruby in project, never met this again and for me still C# or C++ is better than PHP or Ruby :P Now I have to finish my project so I am looking for help here because you are ruby addicted :D